# Dockerized Loopback 4 app not reachable from the host

Tags: node.js, docker, loopback

has anyone successfully dockerize a Loopback-4 (lb4) app?
I set up an lb4 based app and am trying to dockerize it, but although the Docker seems to be running the app, it's not showing on my localhost.

The steps I did:

1. Setup Loopback 4 based app locally
2. Create Dockerfile (code [here](https://github.com/ilusi/sample-lb4))
3. (cd into the dir where Dockerfile is) Build: docker build -t lb4 .
4. Run: docker run -p 3000:3000 lb4

But, the app doesn't show up on http://localhost:3000
The output from running the container:

> trip@1.0.0 prestart /usr/src/app
>   **npm run build**
>
> trip@1.0.0 build /usr/src/app
>   lb-tsc es2017 --outDir dist
>
> trip@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
>   node .
>
> Server is running at http://127.0.0.1:3000
>   Try http://127.0.0.1:3000/ping

---

EDIT

For the sake of conserving the question, relevant code in the repo (step 2) is pasted here,

```
// index.js
const application = require('./dist');
module.exports = application;
if (require.main === module) {
  // Run the application
  const config = {
    rest: {
      port: +process.env.PORT || 3000,
      host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
      openApiSpec: {
        // useful when used with OASGraph to locate your application
        setServersFromRequest: true,
      },
    },
  };
  application.main(config).catch(err => {
    console.error('Cannot start the application.', err);
    process.exit(1);
  });
}
```

Comment: please do  **docker ps** and share the result

Comment: Make sure your app in the container binds to all IP addresses and not just loopback (127.0.0.1). The loopback address is not visible outside of the container.

Comment: your tag in build is sample-lb4 while the image your run is `lb4`, a typo?

Comment: @Igor `CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
1ecde114cd35        lb4                 "npm start"         2 seconds ago       Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   relaxed_minsky`

Comment: @Siyu Typo fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by @Henry in the comment, in your index.js, change to use

```
  host: '0.0.0.0',
```

To know more about the different between localhost (127.0.0.1) and 0.0.0.0, see https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0

PS

It's better to have `npm run build` during the build phrase for faster start at run time.

Comment: This solution works. Thanks @Henry and Siyu (also for the link).

Comment: @ilusi For me commenting the `host` parameter worked. `// host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost'`