# jekyll site in docker serving locally

Tags: docker, jekyll

I'm trying to work with a jekyll site locally using vim and github, all within a docker container on my Windows 10 machine. I want to work in the container like it is a linux virtual machine with my Downloads directory as a volume and jekyll served on port 55.

My docker initialization is

```
docker container run -t -d -p 55:4000 -v ${PWD}:"/home/Downloads/" [container ID]
```

To start the jekyll site I run the following within the docker container

```
jekyll new my-awesome-site
cd my-awesome-site
bundle exec jekyll serve
...
Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

There is nothing showing up locally at `127.0.0.1:55` 
[image: Chrome Error]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM: ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y git && apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev ruby-full build-essential
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apt-get install -y vim

# build ruby configuration
RUN mkdir gems \
    && echo '# Install Ruby Gems to /gems' >> /gems/.bashrc \
    && echo 'export GEM_HOME=/gems' >> /gems/.bashrc \
    && echo 'export PATH=/gems/bin:$PATH' >> /gems/.bashrc \
    && /bin/bash -c "source /gems/.bashrc"

# install jekyll
RUN gem install jekyll bundler

EXPOSE 4000

WORKDIR /home/work
```

`docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
e25f6359ce49        572                 "/bin/bash"         28 minutes ago      Up 28 minutes       0.0.0.0:55->4000/tcp   loving_gagarin
```

Comment: Share the output of `docker ps` with the container running.

Comment: Post is modified on bottom, it doesn't show up at 0.0.0.0:55 either

Comment: You say "There is nothing showing up locally at 127.0.0.1:55". What does that mean? is your browser showing "connection refused"? is it a 404 error?

Comment: 127.0.0.1:55 gives `This page isn't working / 127.0.0.1 didn't send any data / ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Comment: Post updated with chrome error

Answer (score 11):

Use `bundle exec jekyll serve --host 0.0.0.0`

This special host will tell jekyll to serve on all interfaces so that docker can relay the traffic to the outside world.

> As a side note, don't use a port less than 1024; It may cause unexpected troubles.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759617/dockerized-loopback-4-app-not-reachable-from-the-host/53764260#comment94415652_53764260

Comment: Use `--baseurl=""` to prevent empty URL which can broken something.